# Selecting all of the checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which displays a person's info in a table (fields:name, surname, address, etc.) and one of the inputs is a checkbox. The code is as follows:

```
$("#table").append('<tr class="trow'+j+'">'+
                      '<td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+
              '<td>'+member[i].jdate+'</td>'+
              '<td class="users" 

              '<td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+
              '<td id="myaddress'+i+'">'+member[i].address1+' '+member[i].town+'</td>'+

              '<td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+
                                             'class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /> </td></tr>');  
      totrecs++;
      j++;
     }
```

button - `<input type="button" id="selectall" title="Select All" value="Select All" />`

What I am trying to do is create a function sot that when a certain button is clicked, all of the checkboxes will be selected/checked.

I would appreciate any help. Thank You.

Comment: Big anti-pattern using inline JavaScript strings _in JavaScript_.

Comment: That's like meta-spaghetti, no?

Answer (score 1):

Off of the top of my head:

```
$('#table input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: This won't work .. checked is not a property of jQuery Object

Comment: Thanks @undefined for the tip and catching my typo